# "find command -mtime 0" not getting the file i expect

Tags: unix

I am trying to find a file that are 0 days old. Below are the steps I performed to test this

```
$ ls
$ ls -ltr
total 0
$ touch tmp.txt
$ ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-r-----   1 tstUser tstUser           0 Feb 28 20:02 tmp.txt
$ find * -mtime 0
$
$ find * -mtime -1
tmp.txt
$
```

Why is '-mtime 0' not getting me the file?

What is the exact difference between '-mtime 0' and '-mtime -1'?

Im sure there must be other ways to find files that are 0 days old in unix, but im curious in understanding how this '-mtime' actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   -mtime n
          File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the  comments
          for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
          of file modification times.
```

So, -mtime 0 would be equal to: "File's data was last modified 0 hours ago.
While -mtime 1 would be: "File's data was last modified 24 hours ago"

Edit:

```
   Numeric arguments can be specified as

   +n     for greater than n,

   -n     for less than n,

   n      for exactly n.
```

So I guess -1 would be modified within the last 24 hours, while 1 would be exactly one day.

Comment: could u help me understand though how '-mtime 0' would ever be useful??

Comment: Good question. You can find the file(s) that were changed within the hour. Atleast I think thats what it'll do. I haven't really checked this.

Answer (score 6):

This is a not user friendly aspect of `find` - you have to understand how the matching actually works to correctly define your search criteria. The following explanation is based on GNU find (findutils) 4.4.2.

`find` tests `-atime`, `-ctime`, `-mtime` work on 24 hour periods, therefore let's define "file age" as

```
floor (current_timestamp - file_modification_timestamp / 86400)
```

Given three files modified 1 hour ago, 25 hours ago and 49 hours ago

```sh
$ touch -t $(date -d "1 hour ago" +"%m%d%H%M") a.txt
$ touch -t $(date -d "25 hours ago" +"%m%d%H%M") b.txt
$ touch -t $(date -d "49 hours ago" +"%m%d%H%M") c.txt
```

file ages (as defined above) are

```sh
$ echo "($(date +"%s") - $(stat -c %Y a.txt)) / 86400" | bc
0
$ echo "($(date +"%s") - $(stat -c %Y b.txt)) / 86400" | bc
1
$ echo "($(date +"%s") - $(stat -c %Y c.txt)) / 86400" | bc
2
```

Given the above, here's what find does

```sh
$ find -type f -mtime 0 # find files with file age == 0, i.e. files modified less than 24 hours ago
./a.txt
$ find -type f -mtime -1 # find files with file age < 1, i.e. files modified less than 24 hours ago
./a.txt
$ find -mtime 1 # find files with file age == 1, i.e. files modified more than (or equal to) 24 hours ago, but less than 48 hours ago
./b.txt
$ find -mtime +1 # find files with file age > 1, i.e. files modified more than 48 hours ago
./c.txt
```

This shows that `-mtime 0` and `-mtime -1` give equivalent results.

`-mmin` gives the same test with finer granularity - argument is minutes instead of 24 hour periods.

I'm unable to reproduce your problem using the aforementioned version of `find`

```sh
$ touch tmp.txt
$ find * -mtime 0
tmp.txt
$ find * -mtime -1
tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of those three possibilities are as following:

n: exactly n 24-hour periods (days) ago, 0 means today.

+n: "more then n 24-hour periods (days) ago", or older then n,

-n: less than n 24-hour periods (days) ago (-n), or younger then n. *It's evident that -1, and 0 are the same and both means "today"*.

**NOTE**: If you use parameters with find command in scripts be careful when -mtime parameter is equal zero. Some (earlier) versions of GNU find incorrectly interpret the following expression
Sourece: http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/index.shtml